# Docker Caching, how does it really work?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I understand that docker stores every images with layers. If I have multiple users on one development server, and everyone is running the same Dockerfile, but storing the image as, `user1_myapp`. And user2 is storing it as `user2_myapp`. Now again, they are using the same Dockerfile.

The question is, if the image is for example 100mb, are both images taking 100mb each, or are they sharing the same image and using only 100mb instead of 200mb?

Comment: I've done a bit of an experiment, after removing the "duplicate" image stored, it seems that it IS freeing up space. BUT when the second user builds the container, it uses the layer caching from the first user, so the build time is a lot quicker.

Comment: Good. But, can you explain when you removing duplicate, how it freeing up space ?

Comment: @mohan08p So if another user on the network builds the image using the same Dockerfile, it will actually use up space when storing that imagine on that server, but it uses the same cache to create that image

Comment: Docker generates a hash of the result of different instructions. For example, COPY instruction will copy a set of files into the Docker Container/Image. If the hash doesn't change, then Docker will skip over the RUN instructions as it would generate the say result as nothing has changed since last time. If COPY contains new files or changes, then the hash will be different. As such, Docker will execute the RUN instructions. The names/tags have no impact as it's all based on hashes and image ids. A tag is just a friendly name applied at the end.

Comment: when we pass *-no-cache* it will create a different hash and id for that same dockerfile i.e. it just ignores the previous hashes likely resulting in a different image depending on how the Dockerfile has been created.

Comment: Also, you need to take into consideration other general Role based factors like how uses configured into docker group and other user management(workspace on the server), etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the two images will share the same layers if you meet the prerequisites. Docker layers are reused independently of the resulting image name. The requirements to use a cached layer instead of creating a new one are:

- The build command needs to be run against the same docker host where the previous image's cache exists.
- The previous layer ID must match between the cache layer and the running build step.
- The command currently being run, or the source context if you are running a `COPY` or `ADD`, must be identical. Docker does not know if you are running a command that pulls from an external changing resource (e.g. `git clone` or `apt-get update`), which can result in a false cache hit.
- You cannot have disabled caching in your build command.

Keep in mind that layers are immutable, once created they are never changed, just replaced with different layers with new ID's when you run a different build. When you run a container, it uses a copy-on-write RW layer specific to that container, which allows multiple containers and images to point to the same image layers when they get a cache hit.

If you are having problems getting the cache to match in the two builds, e.g. importing a large file and something like the file timestamp doesn't match, consider creating an intermediate image that contains the common files. Then each project can build `FROM` that intermediate image.

Comment: Does priming the cache using docker pull does remove the requirement of the same host? Obviously the configuration between the hosts has to match (e.g. same setting for Selinux)

Comment: @Jonathan To use the layers of a pulled image in your cache, you need to include the flag `--cache-from $image_name` to tell docker to trust the layers from `$image_name`. Otherwise docker will not trust those layers and will perform the build without using them. (There's a risk a malicious image could impersonate the cache of a well known base image.)